# KohanaException : Directory APPPATH\cache must be writable

Tags: kohana-3

i am trying to run a project of kohana-3 in wamp server but getting following error

Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Directory APPPATH\cache must be writable

please help.

Previously this was working fine.

Comment: Not trying to be (too) sarcastic, but have you actually 'read' the error message??

Comment: Yes ofcourse .... My folder is read only... when i uncheck the read only check box it becomes read only after opening again

Comment: Plz tell me the solution for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kohana 3.2 Error on XAMPP with Windows 7: Directory APPPATH\cache must be writable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648213/kohana-3-2-error-on-xampp-with-windows-7-directory-apppath-cache-must-be-writab)

Answer (score 1):

You must set your cache folder to be writable.

Bare in mind that usually in WAMP the PHP user is 'nobody' which doesn't have access to your folders, therefore you must set your folders to be writable.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the file actually exists (application/cache), this folder comes empty with Kohana, and some versioning systems and other software usually delete and ignore empty folders.
If it does not exist, create the folder and insert a blank file in it (ie, empty.txt) if the error persists, give the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah, I read an answer from someone yesterday but I only figured it out today. What I did was this:

- Go inside **application/**
- Create a new folder **cache/**
- Go inside **cache/**
- Create a *empty textfile*. (I created **empty.txt**)

Then thats it. hope it helps

Comment: @bummi can you now remove the -1? it could lead others to ignore my answer without reading it