# Kohana 3.2 Error on XAMPP with Windows 7: Directory APPPATH\cache must be writable

Tags: caching, xampp, kohana

when i´ll look over my site, created with Kohana 3.2 the wild error "Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Directory APPPATH\cache must be writable" appears.

Im using windows 7 with XAMPP and have no idea what to do.

Because the directory "logs" is writable and there are no problems with this dir, but with the cache directory.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem my cache and log is writable but kohana saying it is not..any idea to solve this

Comment: its a long time ago, i think i had checked the wrong directory, can you look if its realy the right path. I think the problem was, that there are more than one cache directories

Comment: my application using kohana was working fine initially.What i did was i replaced my working copy with updated code from my colleque,after that i am facing this problem.I did cache/logs writable still the same problem.Any help

Answer (score 3):

please give 777 permission for application/logs folder.

also give 777 permission for application/cache folder.

mod_rewrite and Curl Should be enabled for kohana. These are all are basic requirements of kohana.

Answer (score 3):

Oh yeah, I read an answer from someone yesterday but I only figured it out today. What I did was this:

- Go inside **application/**
- Create a new folder **cache/**
- Go inside **cache/**
- Create a *empty textfile*. (I created **empty.txt**)

Then thats it. hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Does folder 'cache' exist in your application folder ?

Comment: Doesn't for me.