# Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Directory APPPATH\cache must be writable help needed

Tags: php

Website created with Kohana shows error "Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: Directory APPPATH\cache must be writable" appears.

Im using windows 7 with XAMPP and have no idea what to do.

SYSPATH\classes\kohana\core.php [ 281 ]

```
            Kohana::$cache_dir = APPPATH.'cache';
        }

        if ( ! is_writable(Kohana::$cache_dir))
        {
            throw new Kohana_Exception('Directory :dir must be writable',
                array(':dir' => Debug::path(Kohana::$cache_dir)));
        }

        if (isset($settings['cache_life']))
        {
```

Comment: You need to make sure you have write permissions to APPPATH\cache.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835510/kohanaexception-directory-apppath-cache-must-be-writable/27194753#27194753)

Check whether the file actually exists (application/cache), this folder comes empty with Kohana, and some versioning systems and other software usually delete and ignore empty folders. If it does not exist, create the folder and insert a blank file in it (ie, empty.txt) if the error persists, give the appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the same problem as yours, and I already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31020765/2276894)

It is basically a step by step procedure of @dinhokz answer